# Is $\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n}}$ a Cauchy Sequence in $L^p((0,1))$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Is $(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n}})_{n\in N}$ a Cauchy Sequence in $L^p((0,1))$? and does it converge to $\frac{1}{x}^{\frac{1}{p}}$ (p is a real number bigger or equal to 1)

I think that it isn't a cauchy sequence or doesn't converge to  $\frac{1}{x}^{\frac{1}{p}}$, because if it was, then  $\frac{1}{x}^{\frac{1}{p}}$ would be in $L_p((0,1))$, because the $L^p$ spacess are complete and

$$\left(\int_{(0,1)} \left|\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{n}}\right|^p dL_1(x)\right)^{1/p} = \left(\int_{(0,1)} \left|\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{1 - \frac{p}{n}}\right| dL_1(x)\right)^{1/p} < \infty$$

but

$$\int_{(0,1)} \left(\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\right)^p dL_1(x) = \int_{(0,1)} {\frac{1}{x}} dL_1(x)$$

which diverges

Comment: What is $p$? Are we iterating over $n$? What do you mean by $\mathrm d L^1(x)$?

Comment: Being a Cauchy sequence in $L^p$ does not translate into the question you ask afterwards.

Comment: @DanZimm I added the required information

Comment: @Did can you explain why? I thought if I have a cauchy sequence (with the $L^p norm$) it always converges to some function in $L^p$ because $L^p$ is complete

Comment: @kave that is true, but what you stated isn't the definition of being a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: One could determine whether a sequence $(u_n)$ is Cauchy or not without ever studying *differences* $u_n-u_{n+k}$? Hmmm...

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes thanks for the edit, it looks better now. I'm not that good with latex yet

Comment: @kave : It would be a mistake to think that this is LaTeX.  It's (mostly) the same sort of code used for math notation in LaTeX, but LaTeX does whole documents, numbering the pages, sections and chapters (or leaving them un-numbered if you so direct), justifying the paragraphs, etc. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Did yes if I could prove that it converges it has to be a cauchy sequence too because $L^p$ is complete, right?

Comment: @DanZimm at which point? Where did I give the definition of a cauchy sequence?

Comment: "With other words: Is..." Is not an equivalent statement to saying that it's a Cauchy sequence

Comment: @DanZimm oh yes you are right. I corrected that

Comment: @kave aha! Now I understand what you're asking, before I was very confused :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observe, the limit, if it exists, cannot be $(\frac{1}{x})^{\frac1p}$. That is the pointwise limit, though. If that sequence had a limit in $L^p$, we would have a subsequence converging pointwise almost everywhere to that limit, which couldn't be the actual pointwise limit, and the real pointwise limit would therefore not be the pointwise limit. Let me explain this better. Call the sequence $f_n$. Suppose $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$. Then we know that there exists $f_{n_k}$ a subsequence of $f_n$ that converges pointwise almost everywhere to $f$. $f$, however, could not be $g(x)=(\frac1x^{\frac1p})$, since $g\not\in L^p$, as you showed. So we would have a subsequence of $f_n$ pointwise converging almost everywhere to something different from the real pointwise limit $g$, which could therefore not be the pointwise limit of the whole sequence. This is an evident contradiction. Therefore, $f_n$ can't converge in $L^p$. Since the $L^p$ spaces are complete, it cannot be a Cauchy sequence either, otherwise it would converge, etc etc etc.

A more "constructive" or practical disproof of this statemente (that $f_n$ converges or is Cauchy in $L^p$) is to show it is not bounded. Let's take the $L^p$ norm of $f_n$:
\begin{align*}
\|f_n\|_p^p={}&\int\limits_{[0,1]}\left|\left(\frac1x\right)^{\frac1p-\frac1n}\right|^p\mathrm{d}x=\int\limits_{[0,1]}\left(\frac1x\right)^{1-\frac pn}\mathrm{d}x=-\int\limits_{[+\infty,1]}t^{1-\frac pn}\frac{1}{t^2}\mathrm{d}t={} \\
{}={}&-\frac{1}{-\frac pn}t^{-\frac pn}\Bigg|_{+\infty}^1=-\frac{1}{\frac pn}\lim_{t\to+\infty}t^{-\frac pn}+\frac{1}{\frac pn}=\frac np,
\end{align*}
which for $n\to\infty$ is unbounded, thus proving the sequence cannot converge. Indeed, if it did converge to a limit $f\in L^p$, we would have $\|f_n-f\|_p\to0$, but $\|f_n-f\|_p\geq\|f_n\|_p-\|f\|_p$ which is unbounded for $n\to\infty$.